# C Strings in Structs

Tags: c

I want my struct to carry a string. I defined it like so:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  char* stringy
} myStruct
```

and a function

```
free(char *stringy){
   //structObj is a struct object
   structObj->stringy = stringy
}
```

Is this correct? I have a feeling that since it's a local variable, stringy will be lost, and the pointer will point to garbage.

Sorry, new with C.

Comment: your statement is correct, but does not match the code you have posted.

Comment: Oh Yeah, sorry, I kinda edited this in a hurry. edited

Comment: a function called "free" is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @Duck Yes totally, but I am purposefully redefining free.

Comment: @Secret It is still a bad idea...

Comment: @pablo1977 Yeah, screw what I said, my function was my_free and simply used #define free(ptr) my_free(etc..) So naming a function free is really an inherently bad idea :D

Comment: @Secret: probably a bad idea

Comment: @Secret, Please accept my apology. I've edited your post without noticing that you intentionally called your function `free`. The edit is minor and adds semicolons as your question is not related to syntax. It also renames your `free` function as `myFree`. Does anybody know how to cancel an edit request?

Comment: @nonsensical The editions are suggetions, actually. The mods will vote and they can decide reject it if it is not O.K. Don't worry.

Comment: I hope the mods reject it, I can't seem to figure out how I might leave them a message to reject my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be garbage if you were somehow using `char** stringy`, but `structObj->stringy = stringy` means "you know the thing that `stringy` points to? Now `structObj->stringy` points to that". Of course, it is still possible to unset the value which the pointer is pointing to, and at that point dereferencing will yield garbage.

Here's an example to make it clearer:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 typedef struct mStruct {
  char* stringy;
 } myStruct;

 myStruct * structObj;

 void doSomething(char* stringy)
 {
      structObj->stringy = stringy;
 }

 int main(int argc, char* argv)
 {
      char* a = "abc\n";
      structObj = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
      doSomething(a);
      a = "qxr\n";
      printf(structObj->stringy);
 }// prints "abc\n"
```

Comment: Sorry for being finicky but I believe that you should have gotten a compiler error/warning for the string literal assignment to a non const char pointer.

Comment: @nonsensical I do get a compiler warning, but it served as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If `stringy` is defined in callers of `free` function, as long as they keep the actual string in its place (where `stringy` points), no problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is not any local variable declaration in your code.

You have to declare:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  char* stringy
} myStruct;

free(char *stringy){
   myStruct *structObj;
   structObj->stringy = stringy;
}
```

Pay attention to the semicolon that I've added to the end of the typedef declaration.
This was not not in your code.

The object structObj is a struct whose type is myStruct.

Now, your parameter stringy comes from another site, it is not lost.
But the struct structObj will have duration only inside your "free" function.

**EDIT**

I have fixed an error: the right declaration has to be "pointer to structObj", which is done in this way:

```
  myStruct *structObj;
```

Observe that now myStruct is a non-initialized pointer, so the following assignment is legal:

```
  structObj->stringy = stringy;
```

but will not work.

However I think this goes beyond the scope of the original question...

Answer (score 0):

`myStruct` is type which you defined for your `struct myStruct` .that to you need to  create an object before using.

you need to do like this:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  char *stringy;  
} myStruct_t; //user defined  data type  

 myStruct_t *obj;  

// you need to allocate memory dynamically.   
 obj= (myStruct_t *) malloc(sizeof(myStruct_t));
```

**usage:**

```
scanf("%s",obj->stringy);

printf("%s",obj->stringy);
```

**in function:**

```
  my_free(char *str)  //str is local string 
    {
     obj->stringy=str;
    }
```

---

your can also try this code :

```
typedef struct myStruct {
  char stringy[20]; //char *stringy  
} myStruct_t; //user defined  data type

myStruct_t obj; //object creation
```

**usage:**

```
scanf("%s",obj.stringy);

printf("%s",obj.stringy);
```

**in function:**

```
   my_free(char *str)  //str is local string 
    {
       strcpy(obj.stringy,str);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're correct that as soon as what it points to goes out of scope, it will point to garbage: this is a *dangling pointer*. You'll need to allocate some memory and perform a copy to fix this:

```
add_string(my_struct* s, const char* c)
{
    size_t len = strlen(c);
    s->file = malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(s->file, c);
}
```

Don't forget that you'll need to `free` it when you're done:

```
void destroy_struct(my_struct* s)
{
    free(s->file);
    free(s);
}
```